# No Sound with Console.Beep in UWP

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

Based on this documentation from Microsoft Console.Beep seems to be supported in UWP apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-uwp-10.0

But, when I run the example code it compiles and runs with no exception, but no sound either..

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 with Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform version 6.2.14 on a Windows 11 box.

I've tried turning on "background Media Playback in the Capabilities tab of Package.appxmanifest. That did get WAV files to play using the NAudio package and I could create a set of WAV files that are the tones that I want to play. But that feels like a hack solution.

Comment: I had to run my beep test app with `sudo` to get it to beep, if that means anything

Comment: Looks like it should've worked, the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9e57b6a280308b6e5dc85d1f0c9200cb698fb98b/src/libraries/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Windows.cs#L656) of `Console.Beep` uses Kernel32 Beep, which supposed to be [supported in UWP on Windows 10+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0dll). I would suggest opening an issue in the Github repo, as I believe this is a bug.

Comment: Instead of using Console.Beep, consider using MediaElement to play sounds.

Comment: Does it work on your machine with Win32 api and/or a standard console or winforms/wpf app? (ie : is it just in UWP context?)

Answer (score 0):

In the UWP platform, instead of directly using `Console.Beep` for playing sound, you may need to utilize UWP APIs. For instance, you can play sounds using the `Windows.Media.Playback` APIs. You can either use your WAV files directly or achieve sound playback functionality through an appropriate audio API.